# Debug and Reset push notifications in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, apns

For a couple of days now, my iPhone does not receive push messages any more (I am **not** talking about notifications ... I am talking about push messages that are also used to initiate WahsApp Web/Desktop, among others).

This applies to all apps (WhatsApp, Threema etc.)
It also breaks WhatsApp Web/Desktop.

I applies to all networks (I have tried with various Wifis putting the phone into airplane mode as well as with cellphone network, disabling Wifi).

I have rebooted my phone countless times, even upgraded to the latest and *Reset Network Settings*.

I have tried everything I could find online: Changing date to plus one day, rebooting and changing back. Enabling/Disabling notifications for individual apps.

It seems that something is broken with the iOS system itself.

1. There's gotta be a way to reset push notifications/re-register them. How?
2. What are the steps I can use to to debug?

Comment: If you send an iMessage to your phone when Messages is not runing and visible on screen, do you then get a notification?

Comment: Yes, iMessage works. But none of the apps (Whatsapp, Slack, Outlook, Threema ... )

Comment: Are you sure you haven't just disabled them in the Privacy settings on the phone? - If iMessage works, then you are receiving push messages.

Comment: Yes, as I said 100%. Also note that neiher "WhatsApp Web/Desktop" nor "Threema Web" can connect except when the apps are in the foreground. That always used to work. To my understanding, these rely on **push messages** (not push notifications!) as well, right?

Comment: Are you talking about an app that you run on iPhone? - Or are you using a browser on the iPhone to run WhatsApp Web? Could you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: Push notifications and push messages are the same thing when we're talking about an app on iOS.

Comment: I am talking about using a different machine to connect to WhatsApp/threema on the phone. Yes -- that's what I mean. Since this is not working for multiple apps I don't think it's related to display of notifications and a single app but something is wrong with the iphone/system. There's gotta be a way to reset/debug without loosing data

Comment: I'm really struggling to see why you think this has something to do with push notifications at all. You definitely need to include more information about what actually happened - what does the screen show on the phone and on the PC when you try to connect.

Comment: Just to be clear - I doubt something is wrong with your push notifications, as you have already proven that they work. There's no way to "reset" push notifications besides perhaps turning off and on your phone.